# When trying to fetch secrets from AWS Batch, Getting error - "Missing credentials in config, if using AWS_CONFIG_FILE, set AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1"

Tags: amazon-web-services

My Batch code is running fine in local as it is able to fetch credentials via config file. Env variables are as follows:

```
AWS_CONFIG_FILE=/Users/<user>/.aws/config
AWS_SDK_LOAD_CONFIG=1
```

When this same code is run via Management Console, as we don't have "/Users//.aws/config", it has error. Need to know where can this config file be kept, while in Management Console ?

Answer (score 1):

To give your application IAM permissions in AWS Batch, you use [job role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/batch/latest/userguide/create-job-definition.html):

> For Job role, you can specify an IAM role that provides the container in your job with permissions to use the AWS APIs.

Comment: Enabled "Job Role Configuration" toggle, selected apt role. Done. Thanks !!